# Why is glBlendFunc() not doing anything in my OpenGL ES 2.0 application?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am drawing non-textured triangles whose alpha is being explicitly set to to 0.5 in the pixel shader for testing purposes. My application is based on the Opengl ES prefab provided by Xcode. I have not touched my EAGLView class.

I call

```
glEnable(GL_ALPHA)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SC_ALPHA)
glDrawArrays(...)
```

My clearColor is 0,0,0,1 and CAEAGLayer's format is RGBA8.

The result I see is that no blending of any sort takes place and drawn pixels simply replace what's underneath. I have also attempted to use GL_ONE,GL_ONE.

I tried to set the opaque property of my CAEAGLayer to false. The result seems to be that regardless of blend mode, the color of the drawn pixels is blended with white based on the alpha value. So gl_FragColor of 1,0,0,1 comes out as 1,0,0,1 but 1,0,0,0 comes out as 1,1,1,?

This behavior is consistent on the device and simulator. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable `GL_BLEND` and not `GL_ALPHA`. The `GL_ALPHA` constant has a completely different purpose (as a color channel identifier). So your `glEnable` call actually causes a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error or something the like.

Comment: 1. I'm just curious, is glBlendFunc() available to ES 2.0? I thought with 2.0 we've to do all the blending in fragment shader

Comment: @sid No, blending cannot be done in the fragment shader, as the fragment shader doesn't have access to the previous color of a pixel, it can only write a new color. Even in the newest of newest desktop GL you still have to use `glBlendFunc`, although there have been advancements like `glBlendFuncSeperate` or `glBlendEquation` (but I don't know to which degree ES has these), but there isn't yet a completely programmable blending stage.